# Mask browser URL with GWT

Tags: java, gwt

My GWT app URL when a page is access looks like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#ViewPage;hash=6a
```

or

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html#ViewPage;hash=6a
```

However, this does not look good, is there a way for the GWT client side code to make it look like this, to "mask" it somehow to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/6a
```

Where I have a servlet configured to forward this "shortened" URL to the long URL above so its very safe to make the URL "masked"? Without losing state and history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest possibility I know would be an `URL` like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/#6a
```

Therefore you must configure  index.html as default page. (It must be configured as default response).

You also have to rewrite the history-management. You have to remove the Place-Token from the `URL`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way to do this directly with GWT, since GWT needs access to the code fragment in the URL to manage browsing history and state.

One indirect way to do it would be to embed your GWT module inside an `iframe` that occupies the whole page area. The drawback is that the user would loose the ability to bookmark pages inside the GWT application.

By the way, I don't share your view that it "does not look good". Many popular Web applications use the URL like this, including Gmail. Most users don't care about what's in the URL.

Comment: Thanks for this feedback, actually when I say "does not look good" what I mean is user might copy the long URL during the time its in the app, where what we want to showcase is the short page url...